# Application is background-only

Tags: java, macos, selenium, webdriver, osascript

I am trying to open Google chrome using OSX script to bring it to front.
But I am getting the exception:

```
Application is background-only
```

Code is given below.

```
public void bringBrowserToFront() {
    try {
        String script = "tell app \"Google Chrome.app\" to activate";
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
        engine.eval(script);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println("oasscript error" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Could someone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Because there will be problem in OSX scripting  to open chrome. you will go directly through scripting without using exception e

Comment: can you please clarify. Did not understand.